# malloc():unaligned tcache chunk detected error occurs. error in firebase emulator

Tags: docker, hasura

I am using the firebase emulator in the docker. + hasura(remote-schema)
When the firebase emulator sends many function requests, the data is not answered after the `malloc():unaligned tcache chunk detected error occurs.` (If you request a little bit of data, you’ll get a normal response) How do you solve this problem? My environment is as follows.

Operating System: masOS 12.5 (Firebase Emulator Docker OS: ubuntu22.04)
Docker Desktop: 4.12.0
12 GiB of memory allocated to Docker (average usage 6 to 7 GiB)
CPU assigned to Docker: 8Core
Firebase-Tools version: 11.9.0
Nodejs version 14.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dniy.png)